# Jquery hide function not working if I call inside done method of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

While using ajax call, I'm calling a function of `showMessage()` in the `beforeSend` method of `$.ajax` and inside the `done` method of `$.ajax` I'm calling `hideMessage()`.

The issue is hideMessage() isn't hiding the Message popup. After that, if I execute this function from the console, it worked. Can anyone suggest why is this?

Jquery Version: 1.11.2

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '...',
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function(x) {
    showMessage('Please Wait');
  }
}).done(function(data) {
  hideMessage();
});

function showMessage(text) {
  var mv = null;
  if ($('#messagePopup').size() == 0) {
    mv = $('<div class="wait_popup" id="messagePopup"><div class="wait_div"><div class="wait_content"><div class="text_content"></div></div></div></div>');
    $('body').append(mv);
  } else {
    mv = $('#messagePopup');
  }
  mv.find('.text_content').html(text);
  mv.fadeIn();
  mv.find('.wait_div').delay(400).show('clip');
}

function hideMessage() {
  $('#messagePopup').hide('clip');
}
```

Comment: `.size()` is deprecated, use `.length`

Comment: This is because by the time the request is done, the showMessage functions is still showing the message because of the delays in it. 
You may want to set a flag in hideMessage() and to change the delay to delay(400,callback) within which you would check for that flag before show('clip')

Comment: Always check the browser console for errors. If I use an older version of jQuery, the code works without issue: https://jsfiddle.net/7mc0uzbg/

Comment: @ITgoldman even I removed the delay function but still facing the same issue.

Comment: Both other comments are correct. You should use length instead of .size(). and the code is working on jsfiddle

Comment: @ITgoldman Tried with .length as well... Nothing is working.

Comment: @ChrisG I'm using Jquery version 1.11.2

Comment: @WickyMemon maybe the server response isn't in json, try to `console.log` something inside `.done` to prove that server response is correct.

Comment: Again, the code works for me as-is. Add console.log()s to your code, check the console and find out where exactly it breaks. You can check the $.ajax() call in the console (you may have to turn on `xhr`)